# Display BigDecimal To Arbitrary Precision

Tags: ruby

Somehow I can't find the answer to this using google or SO...

Consider:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

puts (BigDecimal.new(1)/BigDecimal.new(3)).to_s

#=> 0.333333333333333333E0
```

I want the ability to specify a precision of 100 or 200 or 1000, which would print out "0." followed by 100 threes, 200 threes, or 1000 threes, respectively.

How can I accomplish this?  The answer should also work for non-repeating decimals, in which case the extra digits of precision of would be filled with zeros.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `BigDecimal` objects don't have their precision set to a value high enough. I can get a 1000 fractional digits printed if I explicitly specify the required precision of the operation by using `div` instead of `/`:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

puts (BigDecimal.new(1).div(BigDecimal.new(3), 1000)).to_s

#=> 0.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333E0
```

After that, you can limit the number of fractional digits with `round`.